# Problem with pay pal subscriptions

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have implemented pay pal subscriptions (daily) for some service on site. But I have problem with time.
User pay for subscription at 10:30AM I receive IPN message save it to database and give user 24 hours to use service. When after 24 hours pass I want to give user another 24 hours to use service etc.
I tested this yesterday and next IPN message I have received at 1:20PM today. This is more than 24 hours. But I can't let user wait 2 or 3 hours more for payed subscription.
I have option to give user 24 + 5 hours but I don't know is this ideal solution or it is?

Comment: By "next IPN message I have received at .. today", what IPN message are you referring to (what's the txn_type of the message)? What is supposed to happen after 24 hours? I'm not sure of the exact problem; does the IPN message arrive too late? Or is it something else?

Comment: User pay for subscription at 27 Sep 10:30AM. At that time I activate user service. I add to database that service is active from 27 Sep 10:30AM to 28 Sep 10:30AM. So I expect new IPN message at 28 Sep 10:30AM so I can add new row to database that service is active to 29 Sep 10:30AM. The problem is I get that IPN at 27 Sep 1:30PM. So my user can't use service between 10:30AM and 1:30PM

Comment: Subscriptions run on a specific day, not a specific time. So yes, you'll need to build in some leeway to handle that. Ideally the full 24 hours of the day.